# Deleting last new line string

Tags: java, string, recursion, newline

So I've tried pretty much everything to get rid of the last newline character in my code. Its supposed to print a new line after every recursive call except for the last one. Any ideas?

```
public static boolean solve(double target, ArrayList<Double> numbers)
{
    String print = "";
    String newPrint = "";
    double compare = 0;

    boolean done = false;

    for (double num : numbers)
    {
        if (!done)
        {

            ArrayList<Double> remaining = new ArrayList<Double>(numbers);

            remaining.remove(num);

            if (target == num)
            {
                done = true;

            }
            else
            {

                done = solve(target + num, remaining);
                if (done)
                {
                    print += ((int) target + (int) num) + " " + "-" + " " + (int) num + " "
                            + "="
                            + " "
                            + ((int) target + "\n");
                }
                else
                {

                    done = solve(target - num, remaining);
                    if (done)
                    {
                        print += ((int) target - (int) num) + " " + "+" + " " + (int) num + " "
                                + "=" + " "
                                + ((int) target + "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        done = solve(target * num, remaining);
                        if (done)
                        {
                            print += ((int) target * (int) num) + " " + "/" + " " + (int) num
                                    + " " + "=" + " "
                                    + ((int) target + "\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            done = solve(target / num, remaining);
                            if (done)
                            {
                                print += ((int) target / (int) num) + " " + "*" + " "
                                        + (int) num
                                        + " " + "="
                                        + " " + ((int) target + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

    System.out.print(print);

    return done;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you iterate through `numbers.size()-1` with newline and then don''t add the newline for the last one?

Comment: It is very difficult to follow your logic.  Your question is a common problem, and one simple solution would be to only print the newline if there is another recursion.

Comment: Instead of printing a newline after every line except the last one, print a newline *before* every line except the first one.  It's a lot easier to know when you're first than it is to know when you're last.

Comment: I also advise to print it first. @Hasseb Waseem Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
void recursiveF(...) {
    if ... {
        recursiveF(...);
        println();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This approach is effective, but I'd rather use tail recursion or a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The result is a string but you don't want the last character, so remove it:

```
print = print.substring(0, print.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() method. It will remove white spaces, newline etc from beginning and end of string.

System.out.print(**print.trim()**);

Answer (score 0):

**Short** Print the new line character before.

The first thing the recursive function should do is print the new line character.
This way you shift the odd case from the last function call, to the first call, which should not prepend a new line character.

You could add a parameter `String prepend = ""` to the signature of the recursive method, it's empty on the first call, all further calls have it set to `String prepend = "\n"`.
Then you can just print `prepend` without bothering with its content.